# Cypher query to find all entities whose related entities are a subset of a given collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm pretty new to graph databases and have only been messing with Neo4j for the past few days. But, I'm wanting to build a project and hitting a wall right out of the gate.

Say our domain is Recipes and Ingredients. What I'd like to ask the graph is: "Give me all recipes that can be made with only the given collection of ingredients".

Here's a sample graph http://console.neo4j.org/?id=4apn5q

In the graph, Users :HAVE ingredients, and Recipes :REQUIRE ingredients, but it's Ok to ignore the user side for simplification.

Is there a way to write a query that returns recipes that require a collection of ingredients and DO NOT require any ingredients not in the collection? Am I even thinking about this right or is there a better way to go about it? I'm open to any insight.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get do it this way:

- fetch all available ingredients from the user
- fetch a list of all ingredients for each recipe
- compare the lists

.

```
MATCH (u:User { name:'Keith' })-[:HAS]->(availableIngredient) 
WITH collect(availableIngredient) AS availableIngredients 
MATCH (r:Recipe)-[:REQUIRES]->(ingredient) 
WITH r, collect(ingredient) AS ingredients, availableIngredients 
WHERE ALL(x IN ingredients WHERE SINGLE (y IN availableIngredients WHERE x=y)) 
RETURN r, ingredients
```

This query is very greedy since you touch all recipes in your graph. This can be optimized this by starting at your user, traverse the available ingredients and limit recipes to those being reachable from there:

```
MATCH (u:User { name:'Keith' })-[:HAS]->(availableIngredient)<-[:REQUIRES]-(recipe:Recipe) 
WITH recipe, collect(availableIngredient) AS availableIngredients 
MATCH (recipe)-[:REQUIRES]->(ingredient) 
WITH recipe, availableIngredients, collect(ingredient) AS ingredients 
WHERE ALL (x IN ingredients WHERE SINGLE (y IN availableIngredients WHERE x=y)) 
RETURN recipe.name, ingredients
```